# Linq newest group of records

Tags: c#, linq

(Linq)

I have a simple object let's call Dog in a simple List of Dog

```
Dog
  Id  (Unique)
  GroupBarkId
  Name
```

I need to get all the Dogs that have the same **highest** GroupBarkId

```
Id   GroupdBarkId
1    2
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
```

So I'd need the list to have, in this case, the **GroupBarkId equals to 3**.

I don't know the highest GroupBarkId when I do the query

Comment: People are on a down vote frenzy today. Must be a bad Friday. The question is readable, formatted, and clearly explained what he wanted to do.

Comment: But lacks of research,code and the real point where OP got stuck. SO it is not a real question. Just *write it for me*

Comment: @L.B You just described most of Stack Overflow's "good" questions. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dogs = db.Dogs.Where(d => d.GroupdBarkId == db.Dogs.Max(d => d.GroupdBarkId))
                  .ToList();
```

Or first get the maximum Id:

```
var id = db.Dogs.Max(d => d.GroupdBarkId);
var dogs = db.Dogs.Where(d => d.GroupdBarkId == id)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` + `OrderByDescending`:

```
List<Dog> dogsWithHighestGroupBarkId = dogs
    .GroupBy(d => d.GroupBarkId)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Key)
    .First()
    .ToList()
```

Comment: That's better than making sub-query for each item in collection. Btw I think best way in terms of performance will be making two separate queries - one for getting max id, and second for filtering colleciton